# Update Custom Field in Task Project Online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, project-server

Hello I found this article: [Updating Project Server custom fields via JSOM](http://nearbaseline.com/blog/2013/08/updating-project-server-custom-fields-via-jsom-csom/comment-page-1). This article explain about how to update custom field value in Project.

In my case, I am trying to update custom field value in Tasks. But, I got an error :

> PS_DraftTask has no method 'setCustomFieldValue'

Can we update custom field in Tasks? I have managed update some value like `Name` which is standard field in Tasks. My code not to different with the article, but if you want to see it, let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm copying my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853398/updating-task-level-custom-fields/39325738#39325738

JSOM example to update task custom field:

```
var projContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();    
var projects = projContext.get_projects();
var project = projects.getByGuid(projUid).get_draft();
var tasks = project.get_tasks();

var task = tasks.getByGuid(taskUid);

task.set_item(cfIntName, newValue);

var queueJob = project.update();

projContext.waitForQueueAsync(queueJob, 60, 
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(res) {
        // Publish project here
    }), function(error) {

    console.error(error);        
});
```

That should be complete (though I pulled it from a script, so check the success / failure handlers which I truncated).

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

I got some clue in this : [Use CSOM to update project's custom fields](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d79f22f2-7fd2-46af-b778-e189c8611120/use-csom-to-update-projects-custom-fields)

Actually, there's task level code at the bottom of that post.

Comment: but in JSOM not work at all :(

Answer (score 0):

You can update custom field value using this link
http://projectservercode.com/tag/how-to-update-custom-field-using-csom/

Comment: Can you please add details from the link which you have provided? Only links will not help.